# SQL query needs to return primary record and subsidirary records

Tags: sql-server, select, rows, subquery

Let me describe this as best I can, this is regarding SQL Server.

There is a main table with one record per participant, there is a sub table with at MOST 5 records per participant.

I need to be able to return ALL the records within the main table along with the sub table records per participant within the same record in the SELECT query.

Example:

```
Main Table:
   Participant_ID,
   Program
Sub Table:
   Participant_ID,
   Skill_Set_ID,
   Rating

SQL Query results:
    Participant_ID, Program, Skill_Set_ID_1, Rating_1, Skill_Set_ID_2, Rating_2, Skill_Set_ID_3, Rating_3, Skill_Set_ID_4, Rating_4, Skill_Set_ID_5, Rating_5
```

Basically rows to columns idea.

How can I get this done? I am at a total loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select mt.Participant_ID, mt.Program, 
       st1.Skill_Set_ID as Skill_Set_ID_1, st1.Rating as Rating_1, 
       st2.Skill_Set_ID as Skill_Set_ID_2, st2.Rating as Rating_2, 
       st3.Skill_Set_ID as Skill_Set_ID_3, st3.Rating as Rating_3, 
       st4.Skill_Set_ID as Skill_Set_ID_4, st4.Rating as Rating_4, 
       st5.Skill_Set_ID as Skill_Set_ID_5, st5.Rating as Rating_5, st5.Skill_Text
       st6.Skill_Set_ID as Skill_Set_ID_6, st6.Rating as Rating_6, st6.Skill_Text
       st7.Skill_Set_ID as Skill_Set_ID_7, st5.Rating as Rating_7, st7.Skill_Text
    from main_table mt
        left join sub_table st1
            on mt.Participant_ID = st1.Paticipant_ID
                and st1.Skill_Set_ID = 1
        left join sub_table st2
            on mt.Participant_ID = st2.Paticipant_ID
                and st2.Skill_Set_ID = 2
        left join sub_table st3
            on mt.Participant_ID = st3.Paticipant_ID
                and st3.Skill_Set_ID = 3
        left join sub_table st4
            on mt.Participant_ID = st4.Paticipant_ID
                and st4.Skill_Set_ID = 4
        left join sub_table st5
            on mt.Participant_ID = st5.Paticipant_ID
                and st5.Skill_Set_ID = 5
                and st5.Skill_Text = 'Skill A'
        left join sub_table st6
            on mt.Participant_ID = st6.Paticipant_ID
                and st6.Skill_Set_ID = 5
                and st6.Skill_Text = 'Skill B'
        left join sub_table st7
            on mt.Participant_ID = st7.Paticipant_ID
                and st7.Skill_Set_ID = 5
                and st7.Skill_Text = 'Skill C'
```

Comment: This could work, but I just reviewd teh table and there could be up to 7 skill set records, but there is a stipulation, skill set 1 - 4 are static with different id, however skill set 5 - 7 are optional and have the same id.

Comment: @mattgcon: How would you differentiate 5-7 if they have the same ID?

Comment: by an optional column with the skill type text entered

Comment: @mattgcon: Extended my answer to accommodate the new requirements.

Comment: Ok this is going to work. This database is a total train wreck so I am going to just do this suggestion for now until I get to redo the entire db. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Main_Table, Sub_Table
WHERE Main_Table.Participant_ID = Sub_Table.Participant_ID;
```

Does SQL Server use standard SQL?

Comment: This will not work. The main table does not contain any of the information within the sub table except for the participant ID

Comment: @mattgcon: What do you mean? The only intersecting data you need is the value of Participant_ID, and `SELECT *` will return all columns from both tables. Mind you, it will return the cartesian product, so I would advise using `SELECT DISTINCT *` if you want to filter out redundant tuples.

Comment: That is the thing, all data from BOTH tables needs to be on one line, (I.E. each participant will only have one record int he return query results) If I do it that way it would return a maximum of 5 rows per participants. and I do not and cannot have that

Comment: Oh, sorry, misinterpreted the question. What are you passing the data to that it cannot be represented in 5 rows? And if the data has to be in that format, you could alter the sub table to have the different ratings under the skill id, and having five different skill_set_n attributes.

Comment: I am passing it to a report (Access report actually, old system and I inherited it so stuck with the layout for now) Cannot change anything right now in terms of table structure

Comment: The only other solution I can think of is to have 5 joins by renaming sub table as 5 different names and then using those names in the result, like `SELECT Main.P_ID, Prog, Sub1.Rating, Sub2.Rating, Sub3.Rating, Sub4.Rating, Sub5.Rating`, but there must be much better solutions than this.

Comment: well how would I go about doing that join then. I do also have to state that 3 of the subtable records are guaranteed while the other 2 out of 5 are optional and may not exist.

Comment: I'll be using abbreviations:
`SELECT Main.P_ID, Prog, Sub1.Rating, Sub2.Rating, ..., Sub5.Rating
FROM Main, Sub as Sub1, Sub as Sub2, Sub as Sub3, Sub as Sub4, Sub as Sub5
WHERE Sub1.Set = 1
AND Sub2.Set = 2
AND Sub3.Set = 3
AND Sub4.Set = 4
AND Sub5.Set = 5;`
and use limit rows, although I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: Oh geez, sorry, left out the most essential part... `SELECT TOP 1 Main.P_ID, Prog, Sub1.Rating, Sub2.Rating, ..., Sub5.Rating FROM Main, Sub as Sub1, Sub as Sub2, Sub as Sub3, Sub as Sub4, Sub as Sub5 WHERE Sub1.Set = 1 AND Sub1.P_ID = 'P_ID' AND Sub2.Set = 2 AND Sub2.P_ID = 'P_ID' AND Sub3.Set = 3 AND Sub3.P_ID = 'P_ID' AND Sub4.Set = 4 AND Sub4.P_ID = 'P_ID' AND Sub5.Set = 5 AND Sub5.P_ID = 'P_ID';`